# ¿Se puede mejorar este código?

Tags: swift, revisión-de-código

Me estoy preguntando, si de alguna manera, se puede mejorar o almenos achicar el siguiente código:

```
func addCourse(cursoRecibido: Course) throws {
        let curso = Course()
        if let author = cursoRecibido.author {
            curso.author = author
        } else {
            throw addCourseError.emptyAuthor
        }
        if let title = cursoRecibido.title {
            curso.title = title
        } else {
            throw addCourseError.emptyTitle
        }
        if let duration = cursoRecibido.duration {
            curso.duration = duration
        } else {
            throw addCourseError.emptyDuration
        }
        if let date = cursoRecibido.uploadDate {
            curso.uploadDate = date
        } else {
            throw addCourseError.emptyUploadDate
        }
        if let views = cursoRecibido.views {
            curso.views = views
        }
         dao.addCourse(curso)
    }
```

La clase de este método trata sobre el business logic para guardar el curso en sqlLite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deberías empezar por el hecho de preguntarte porque creas un nuevo curso para añadir cuando ya te viene uno en la función como parámetro. Quizás deberías verificar que todos los campos están rellenados y entonces guardarlo.

Aún así, hay muchas posibles soluciones. Te paso dos, una reduciendo tú código, y otra como yo lo haría:

**Solución 1**

```
func addCourse(cursoRecibido: Course) throws {

    // Verifico que todos los datos existen
    guard let author = cursoRecibido.author, title = cursoRecibido.title, duration = cursoRecibido.duration, uploadDate = cursoRecibido.uploadDate, views = cursoRecibido.views else {

        // Lanzar excepción general que diga algo como "Todos los datos son requeridos"
        throw addCourseError.AllDataRequired
    }

    // Creo el ccurso
    let curso = Course()
    curso.author = author
    curso.title = title
    curso.duration = duration
    curso.uploadDate = uploadDate
    curso.views = views

    // Añado el curso
    dao.addCourse(curso)

}
```

**Solución 2**

```
func addCourse(cursoRecibido: Course) throws {

    // Verifico que todos los datos existen
    guard let author = cursoRecibido.author, title = cursoRecibido.title, duration = cursoRecibido.duration, uploadDate = cursoRecibido.uploadDate, views = cursoRecibido.views else {

        // Lanzar excepción general que diga algo como "Todos los datos son requeridos"
        throw addCourseError.AllDataRequired
    }

    // Añado el curso
    dao.addCourse(cursoRecibido)

}
```

Comment: Claro haciendo uno general es con menos código pero si quiero una respuesta(un catch) para cada error no habría manera de achicarlo por lo que veo

Comment: Entonces no, tienes que ir campo por campo para devolver el error correspondiente